# How can i persist android activity state?

Tags: android, android-fragments, state, onactivityresult

I have an activity that have navigation drawer and many fragments. In one fragment there is an option to attach an image from gallery. I am calling the following method from fragment for that

```
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,MainActivity.GALLERY_PICTURE);
```

It is calling activities onActivityResult and working for some images. But most of the time, when i select an image from gallery it will redirect to the activity ,but it have the initial fragment. How can i solve this issue?Is this because of activity can't persist it's state? I want all the fragments that are in backstack and its state.